# Ubuntu 21.04. How do I check an rsync backup set?

Tags: backup, rsync

I’ve been using Timeshift and have about 200+ snapshots (190GB) in my Timeshift backup set. What are the commands to check this backup set? I want to make sure the backup set is not corrupted.

Restic has the commands ‘check’, ‘prune’ and  ‘cleanup’. What are the similar commands for rsync? I checked an rsync command list page and didn’t find anything relevant.

Comment: The most logical way to test this would be to use a VM that has TimeShift installed and restore a backup to that. This will let you check the completeness of a restoration 

Comment: @matigo Thanks. Great idea.